# Не выходит настроить автовход в LXDE (Lubuntu)

Tags: lxde

Я пытался настроить автовход в Lubuntu 15, но у меня, к сожалению, ничего не получилось. Вот что я делал:

---

В файле `/etc/xdg/lubuntu/lxdm/lxdm.conf` изменил `autologin` и `timeout`:

```
[base]
## uncomment and set autologin username to enable autologin
autologin=orangepi
## uncomment and set timeout to enable timeout autologin,
## the value should >=5
timeout=0
## default session or desktop used when no systemwide config
session=/usr/bin/startlubuntu
## uncomment and set to set numlock on your keyboard
# numlock=0
## set this if you don't want to put xauth file at ~/.Xauthority
# xauth_path=/tmp
## greeter used to welcome the user
greeter=/usr/lib/lxdm/lxdm-greeter-gtk
[server]
## arg used to start xserver, not fully function
# arg=/usr/bin/X -background vt1
[display]
## gtk theme used by greeter
gtk_theme=Clearlooks
## background of the greeter
bg=/usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers/lubuntu-default-wallpaper.png
## if show bottom pane
bottom_pane=1
## if show language select control
lang=1
## if show keyboard layout select control
keyboard=0
## the theme of greeter
theme=Lubuntu
[input]
[userlist]
## if disable the user list control at greeter
disable=0
## whitelist user
white=
## blacklist user
black
```

Однако, автовхода все равно нет. Появляется экран входа. На форуме писали добавить в файл `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` строки:

```
autologin-user=orangepi
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Но тогда LXDE попросту не запускается!

---

Подскажите, как можно настроить автовход в систему (логин `orangepi`)?

Comment: А когда не запускается - какие-то ошибки в каких-нибудь файлах журналов есть?

Comment: @МАН69К, честно говоря — не знаю. При запуске выскакивают "Failed", но я ничего не успеваю прочитать.